# Google Deep Learning VM spawning too many /opt/deeplearning/bin/run_diagnostic_tool.sh processes

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Google Deep Learning VM, Version: tf2-cpu.2-11.m102 I find it is automatically spawns too many /opt/deeplearning/bin/run_diagnostic_tool.sh processes, consuming lot of cpu. is it possible to stop running these diagnostic jobs, for my work I actually don't need these jobs to be running.

I tried to kill them manually, but there seems to be a cron job which spawns them again.

Answer (score 2):

Comment out the line in `/etc/rc.local`

```
#/opt/deeplearning/bin/schedule_diagnostic_check.sh
```

Do a reset of crontab

```
sudo crontab -r
```

Do a reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

It should no longer swarm your machine